# Nginx Controller on GKE with TCP Load Balance timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a nginx ingress controller on GKE, it is behind an TCP LB from GCP.
We have some requests that take longer than 30s to process, and the TCP LB seems to be killing the connection with aounrd this timeout (30~35s).

How can I change the LB timeout?

Any other workaround so that the LB does not close the connection would be helpful too. (maybe on nginx to send some packet to keep alive?)

Observation: the HTTP LoadBalancer has this config, I know. But I need it on TCP. In fact, this ingress controller was installed acording to these docs on GCP:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

Comment: digao_mb, did you by chance figure out the root cause? I ended up having exactly the same effect on ingress-nginx-3.23.0 installed by helm.

Comment: UPDATE: with exactly the same syndromes as the author had described, in my case, there appeared to be my company's Gateway in the middle with its own timeout that cut the connection after 20s. In the browser I saw 502 code and 499 in ingress-nginx logs.